# Add glyphicon to JS code?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add glyphicon in JS file used for showing error message. Is that possible and if it is how can I do that?

Here is the current code:

```
if (freeSpotFound == false) { 
    raiseError("Error!", "#add-item-error");
    return;
}
```

Is it possible to add glyphicon before the "Error!" text?

Comment: It is possible, if your `raiseError` function accepts html content

Comment: what does `raiseError` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what `raiseError()` does
Try adding some HTML, and see if it works

```
if (freeSpotFound == false) { 
    raiseError("<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span> Error!", "#add-item-error");
    return;
}
```